# Issues with functions Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I have a code that I am trying to understand.

```
def custom_forecast(request, pk=None):

    if pk is not None:
        param = get_object_or_404(Parameters.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) | Q(system_parameter=True)), pk=pk) #iza l model

        form = ForecastForm(request.POST or None, instance=param)
    else:
        form = ForecastForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            if 'save' in request.POST:#kerml sayev
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.user = request.user
                obj.type = "custom_forecast"
                obj.save()
                messages.info(request, 'Saved!')
                return redirect(obj.get_forecast_url()) 
            else:
                obj = ForecastQueue.create(request.user, 'custom_forecast', json.dumps(request.POST)
                obj.save()
                return redirect(obj.get_url())
        else:
            data = { 'active_page': 'custom_forecast',
                    'form': form,
                    'display_result': False  }
    else:
        data = { 'active_page': 'custom_forecast',
                'form': form,
                'display_result': False  }

    data['system_params'] = Parameters.objects.filter(system_parameter=True).all()

    return render(request, 'custom_forecast.html', data)
```

Basing on my basic knowledge it is a method to display a forecast form if the parameters are not in the database (pk=none)
The first else:

```
else:
    obj = ForecastQueue.create(request.user, 'custom_forecast', json.dumps(request.POST)
    obj.save()
```

Is to create user before choosing parameters ?

Comment: The first line inside the `else` block is invalid. There's a `)` missing.

Comment: No - You havn't pasted enough information but at a ugess ForecastQueue is an model. Ie. that else (the second one, not first), is creating a ForecastQueue for that user based upon json data in the request. (the user to be in request.user will already be created and logged in, (or it will be anonymous)). more information is needed to diagnose completly

Comment: what you want actually? you question is not understandable

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the code...

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to define [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) class method for model. 
`ForecastQueue.create(...)` creates instance of `ForecastQueue` model.
`request.user` is just an argument for this method.

Comment: Aha okay thank you. so if I put @login required for this class isn't the same ?

Comment: No, it's not. Passing an argument to a method is something completely different from decorating a view.